# How to load Ubuntu Server automatically in Grub

Tags: 12.10, server, grub2

This is my   `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console


# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

But when I have a power failure, then the Ubuntu Server 12.10 stays at this screen. I've tried to solve it editing grub but doesn't seem to have an affect. Since I don't have display attached, I need it to start automatically Ubuntu every time.

Thanks!

[image: Ubuntu Grub]

Comment: Take a look at [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header` and change line 236 (this line is in the
>   `make_timeout ()` function) to:
>
> ```
> set timeout=0
> ```
>
> 1. For `timeout=-1`, there will be no countdown and thus the menu will display.
> 2. For `timeout=0`, menu will not display even for a failed startup.
> 3. For `timeout>=1`, menu will display for the specified number of seconds.
>
> Run `sudo update-grub` after the change have been made. Special thanks
>   to [McCunha](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=963887) on Ubuntu Forums for the above tip.
>
> The above change, however, still causes GRUB2 to boot into text
>   graphics mode. Thus, an additional change is required. Edit
>   `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and change line 188 to:
>
> ```
> set linux_gfx_mode=keep
> ```
>
> Once again, run `sudo update-grub` after the change has been made.

**Source: [Last Boot Failed or Boot into Recovery Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Last_Boot_Failed_or_Boot_into_Recovery_Mode)**